# :Set project application settings to defaults

Tags: c#, visual-studio, default, application-settings

I'm trying to use the application setting in  my c# project. However, Properties.Settings.Default.Reset() actually sets all properties to their system defaults (a String will be set to null and not the value i set as base).

Is there a way to set default values for properties so that i can call a method to set them to default?

Edit :
The question concerns setting to default individual properties, not all of them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify defaults for user settings from Visual Studio, in the Properties window of the project, in the Settings tab. Just enter something in the Value column.

The values you specify get saved in app.config, in the `userSettings` section (you can edit them there, too), and they will be used when calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Reset()`.

To understand what happens: when you call `Save()`, the current values of the user settings are saved in a file under the user profile folder in Windows, and when you call `Reset()` the values from the app.config file from the application folder are used to overwrite them.

If you just want to reset an individual setting (SomeSetting) to its default, you could do:

```
Settings.Default.SomeSetting = Settings.Default.Properties["SomeSetting"].DefaultValue;
Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i realized i was being too vague, i edited the original post to give more precisions on what i was interested in.

Comment: I must admit i overlooked the .Properties part when using Settings, otherwise i might've found it without having to ask a question here. In any case, thanks for the fast answer.